# How to avoid line through from span when checked

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a list of items(`li`).

Example

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="checked">Groceries <span>&#215;</span></li>
    <li>Medicine <span>&#215;</span></li> 
    <li>Shopping <span>&#215;</span></li>
</ul>
```

trying to use `line-through` when any item(`li`) is selected but I don't want to mark the line through to cross icon(`span`).

I am trying to do text decoration none for span but it's not working

CSS

```css
.list li.checked {
    text-decoration: line-through;          /* when li checked */
}

.list li.checked span {
    text-decoration: none !important;       /* Trying to discard 
    underline for span */
}
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: Are you stuck with that HTML structure or can you change it?

Comment: I'm adding span and button both to achieve cross interaction and span line-through

Answer (score 2):

You should flip-flop what you are doing. Declare line-through for `span` and put it around the text.

```css
.list li.checked span {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="checked"><span>Groceries</span> &#215;</li>
  <li><span>Medicine</span> &#215;</li> 
  <li><span>Shopping</span> &#215;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In this case, my style and event listener won't work for a cross icon, and I need to keep 2 spans as per your suggestion

Comment: @akhtarvahid If you have a cross icon that is interactable, then it should be a button, then you can add event listeners to that button.